# Bot does not answer some questions in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

A bot channel was registered on Azure which was developed at node.js. Bot was published in Teams as an application, but some questions Bot answers and others do not, does it happen only within Teams, just stands still and does not present the answer?
I inform you that I perform a test on Azure in Test your Web Chat and Bot answers all questions without problems.

Comment: Does Bot respond if you post the same question again to the Bot? Just trying to understand if it's specific to question or it's random. Are you getting any errors in your backed code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. You don't provide any proper detail or any code that we can debug. It's very hard to figure out the behavior if we don't have any context, except for your short description.

Comment: @wixavier, Please provide more details to suggest anything.

Comment: reading the text https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#messaging-extensions, I found NGrok here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519187/test-a-bot-functionality-in-teams-using-ngrok I managed to move forward.